# Stanford CoreNLP Chinese model training

Tags: java, error-handling, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am currently trying to train my own Chinese NER model with CoreNLP however when executing the training command I get an FileNotFoundException. I have seen post about this error being fixed in CoreNLP 3.5.0, however I am using 4.1.0 and it is still occurring.

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \u\nlp\data\chinese\distsim\xin_cmn_200907-201012.ldc.seg.utf8.c1000 (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.inputStreamFromFile(IOUtils.java:523)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromFile(IOUtils.java:558)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.setNextObject(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:189)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory$ReaderIterator.<init>(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:161)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ReaderIteratorFactory.iterator(ReaderIteratorFactory.java:98)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank$OBIterator.<init>(ObjectBank.java:411)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.objectbank.ObjectBank.iterator(ObjectBank.java:250)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERFeatureFactory.initLexicon(NERFeatureFactory.java:588)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERFeatureFactory.init(NERFeatureFactory.java:389)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.reinit(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:210)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.<init>(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:190)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.<init>(CRFClassifier.java:181)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.chooseCRFClassifier(CRFClassifier.java:2919)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:2930)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \u\nlp\data\chinese\distsim\xin_cmn_200907-201012.ldc.seg.utf8.c1000 (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.inputStreamFromFile(IOUtils.java:516)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: does the file exist in that location?

Comment: i believe the file is supposed to be inside of the Chinese model jar file which I have downloaded in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

That file is not publicly distributed by us. I can ask if we are allowed to share it or not. In the meantime you need to change your training properties to set `useDistSim = false` to avoid this error.